# Unexpected deployment behaviour of Camel routes in Karaf

Tags: deployment, apache-camel, multiple-instances, apache-karaf

So, I do have an installation of Apache Karaf 3.0.4 with a root instance and two child instances. First child is the productive one and the other one was cloned from that for a testing environment. 
Both child instances are run as Windows services via the wrapper, the root is stopped.
The instances serve as runtime for some Apache Camel routes compiled as OSGi bundles as jar-files. The bundles are deployed by copying them to the deploy folder of the respective instance.

My Problem is, that if I'm deploying to either instance the bundle will also be  installed to the other instance.

For example, 
I'm running a 1.0.0 in prod and 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT in test 
and 
I'm undeploying the 1.0.0 and deploying a 1.0.1 to prod 
the result is, that prod is prod is running 1.0.1 - as expected - and test will be running 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT **and** the release of 1.0.1.

Could somebody point me towards at what causes that behaviour? Is it something related to the test-instance being a clone? Is there any config I need to check?

Thanks in advance, h.

Comment: Is it not the case that they are somehow sharing the same deploy folder?

Comment: Well in fact this is, what the shown behavior suggests. But every instance has its own folder structure and the documentation states otherwise https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/instances.html

Comment: The question really is, if there is a way to change this behavior.

Comment: Hmm, strange, try posting this on the Karaf nabble forum where the Karaf developers and users are active.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to recreate your scenario. 
instance:create prod
instance:clone prod test
instance:list

The test instance seems to have the same ssh port as prod. It also seems to use the same KARAF_BASE dir. So it also uses the same deploy folder.

I think you should not use clone to create the test instance.

Comment: Yeah really bad design to mix prod and test in the same karaf installation

Comment: Thx for your feedback. Of course I did change the ports (ssh, RMI-registry and RMI server). So that's not the point.
Besides that possibly being a bad design decision my original question remains unanswered: Is this behavior intentional?

Comment: BTW: I think you're wrong about them sharing the KARAF_BASE dir. That's configured in the *-wrapper.conf and is pointing to the correct locations.
Anyway I'm gonna seperate the test env.

Comment: Can you try to create the test instance without cloning it from prod. I think this should work better. If this also does not work then it might be a bug in karaf on windows. The start scripts of the instance for linux and windows look very different.